# what is the filesize limit for ota ios app distribution?

Tags: ipad, applications, wifi

i'm trying to deploy an ipad application ota, however i am getting the error:

- unable to download application
- "appname" could not be downloaded at this time.

the ipa file itself is 1.8gb and the server is on the same wifi network as the ipad (ipad 2 wifi-only, ios 5). is there a filesize limit?

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple an over the air download (mobile network) is 20MB. I don't think there's any limit for a WiFi based download although it's likely more reliable to download via iTunes and sync back to the device.

Overall app size limit is 2GB.